# Add button not showing up in Google Chrome Flash Settings section

Tags: google-chrome

I want to give permission to some specific url to run flash but in google chrome in the settings section the add button is not available.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "add button" will popup when you browse to a website URL that requests it. It will popup under the TLS (https) icon in the URL to confirm the permission.

*https://some.website requests permission to use flash? [ ALLOW / BLOCK ]*

If you click "ALLOW" it will then display *https://some.website:443* in the list displayed above. FYI, port 443 is normally the default for SSL tunnelling. 1935 is the port for adobe connect, more info can be found here if you get connection issues after allowing:

https://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-connect/kb/configure-ports-1935-443-80.html

Also, be wary of allowing access to non-SSL (plaintext), due to many exploits involving non secure connections.